# Directly evaluate a SQL cell and use as a filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter

I'm working using SQL Server (2012), and am trying to find out if there's a way to evaluate the value of a cell in a join and use that as filter text.

The situation:
I have a list of Work Orders. Each Work Order has an Asset Group and a Type. Types in turn have descriptions etc in a lookup table. I have a list of filter criteria, and they change by Asset Group - for instance Asset Group X may want Types A and B, Asset Group Y may want Types B and C, Asset Group Z may want Types where the description includes the word 'Motor'.

What I would like to do is create a table of Asset Groups and their associated criteria eg {X, Type IN ('A', 'B')}, {Z, Description LIKE '%motor%'} and have that criteria evaluated within the query to determine which Work Orders are returned.

Comment: You'll need to use string manipulation to build SQL dynamically and then execute that (see [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). ***NOTE*** unless you are very careful you'll likely introduce SQL Injection Vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own query like this when you have variable column/table names:

```
DECLARE @SQL as NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'select ' + @columname + ' from ' + tableName ......
EXEC(@SQL)
```